# Knockout JS Implementation with Phtml ReferenceError: Unable to process binding

Tags: javascript, knockoutjs, image-upload, file-upload, input

After a lot of search in this forum I have decided to write a question by myself.

I am trying to integrate my knockout page into a phtml file in way to update the input layout after a file has been uploaded, but when I try to load the page I face this error:

```
ReferenceError: Unable to process binding "event: function(){return {change:myFunction} }"
Message: myFunction is not defined
```

Actually I'm sure that the JS file is actually loaded.

Following you can find the code:

<MODULE_NAME>/widget/pending_page.phtml

```
<form method="post" action="" enctype="multipart/form-data">
       <div class="container">
           <div class="well" data-bind="fileDrag: fileData">
               <div class="form-group row">
                   <div class="col-md-6">
                   </div>
                   <div class="col-md-6">
                       <input type="file" name="file" id="file" accept="image/*" data-bind="event: {change : myFunction }">
                   </div>
               </div>
           </div>
           <button class="btn btn-default" type="submit">Submit</button>
       </div>
   </form>
```

<MODULE_NAME>/js/pending_page

```
    [
        'ko',
        'jquery',
        'uiElement'
    ],
    function(
        ko,
        $,
        Component
    ){
    "use strict";

        return Component.extend({

            defaults: {
                template: '<MODULE>/widget/pending_page'
            },

            initObservable: function () {
                this._super()
                    .observe({
                        files: []
                    })

                this.files.subscribe(function() {}, this);
            },

            myFunction: function(){
                console.log("i'm hereeeeeeeeeeeeeeeee")
            },
        })

});
```

May someone help me? I'm going crazy about that.

Thanks!

Comment: this looks like a context problem, try this on the template data-bind="event: {change : $parent.myFunction }" or data-bind="event: {change : $parent.myFunction() }"

Comment: already tryied, also with "$root" but still nothing happens

Answer (score 0):

Try Replace, this below line

```
console.log("i'm hereeeeeeeeeeeeeeeee")
```

Replace with

```
console.log("I am here");
```

As your `single quote '` can conflict with javascript.

Comment: still same issue... :(

Comment: Where you used/write this `event: function(){return {change:myFunction} }` in the code, may you please share that code also, replace that with `event: function(){return {change:myFunction()} } `

Comment: actually it is the `data-bind="event: {change : myFunction }"` but it gets updated like so in the console